# How to display count result to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have attendance table then I perform count to total all the Present(P)Absent(A)Late(L) now how can I show it to blade template inside the html input  with 3 separated value example: value=P, value=A, value=L;
right now with my code I'm getting it as all

**controller:**

```
public function get_status(){

$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-03-31');
$atnds = DB::table('attendances')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 'status')
                 ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->where('lead_id', '=', 1)
                 ->get();

                 return view('total',compact('atnds'));}
```

**DD RESULT**

```
[{"total":7,"status":"A"},{"total":9,"status":"L"},{"total":65,"status":"P"}]
```

Comment: how do you want to show it in html ?

Comment: using input element sir 1 for P one for A one for L

Comment: you just want to show it in tabular format ?

Comment: the input box can be anyware in my page

Comment: you mean the `total` value and `status` value in input box ?

Comment: Only the total sir foreach status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want with input then you can use it like this

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr><th>Status </th> <th>Total</th></tr>
    @foreach($atnds as $at)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $at->status }}</td>
            <td><input type="text" value ="{{ $at->total }}" /></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

In blade you could use

```
<table style="width:100%">
@foreach($atnds as $ad)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $ad->total }}</td>
    <td>{{ $ad->status }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

If you want to break them out i would do so before returning it to the blade

```
$status = []
foreach($atnds as $ad) {
    $status[$ad->status] => $ad->total
}
$status = collect($status);

return view('total',compact('status'));
```

and in the blade you should now be able to do

```
{{ $status->L }}
```

or

```
{{ $status['L'] }}
```

Comment: is there a way to put the result into input box?

Comment: @Grace just paste that into the input box. If you want it as a value of an input use <input value="{{ $ad->total }}">

Comment: its compiled together how to separate P,L,A

Comment: @Grace edited my answer, not sure if thats what you meant, have not tested if it works but it should ;)